# Что за проблема c подключением вложенных библиотек?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Создаю в Qt Creator, но думаю, что проблема не в нём...

Создаю статическую библиотеку lib1 в Qt без использования QtCore. Проект получается, по-умолчанию, содержащий файлы lib1.cpp и lib1.h, 
в которых описан пустой класс Lib1 (только пустой конструктор).

Создаю тестовое приложение "Проект без Qt", которое так и называется test, подключаю к нему эту либу - всё работает.

Теперь создаю также как и lib1 статическую библиотеку lib2.

lib2.cpp:

```
#include "lib1.h"
#include "lib2.h"

Lib2::Lib2() {
    Lib1 *lib1 = new Lib1();
}
```

Компилирую библиотеку Lib2 - пока всё работает как надо.

Вставляю в своё приложение строчку:

```
Lib2 *lib2 = new Lib2();
```

И тут появляется странная ошибка:

> Undefined reference to Lib1::Lib1() в файле lib2.cpp

Что за странная ошибка? Что я делаю не так?

---

```
TEMPLATE = app 
CONFIG += console c++11 
CONFIG -= app_bundle 
CONFIG -= qt 
SOURCES += main.cpp 

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib1/ -llib1 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib1 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib1 

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../lib1/liblib1.a 
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib2/ -llib2 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib2 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib2 
unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../lib2/liblib2.a
```

Comment: Покажите `.pro`-файлы.

Comment: TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib1/ -llib1

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib1
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib1

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../lib1/liblib1.a

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib2/ -llib2

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib2
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib2

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../lib2/liblib2.a

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается... Важен порядок линковки библиотек. Если сначала линковать с lib1 а потом -- с lib2, и в test нет ссылок на lib1, то будет то, что вы видите. Нужно либо упорядочить библиотеки так, чтобы сначала шли те, что обращаются ко внешним функциям, а потом -- те, что эти функции определяют.

Comment: Классика работы алгоритма линкера ld, описанная вдоль и поперек.